# Computing a limit of $x^{1-\epsilon}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I'm wondering whether this limit can be evaluated.

I have no much experience in real analysis, so, looking for suggestions and intuition here.

So, I'm interested in computing the limit, or actually know what is the limit value of

$\lim_{x \to \infty , \epsilon\to 0} x^{1-\epsilon}$

My intuition is that may simply be indetermined

Comment: Try rewriting it as $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, \epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x^\epsilon}$

Answer (score 0):

The double limit should be formalized as the following, assuming that the value is $L$:

For every $\eta>0$, there exist some $M>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that for every $x,\epsilon$ with $x\geq M$ and $0<|\epsilon|<\delta$, then $|x^{1-\epsilon}-L|<\eta$.

Take $\eta=1$, then we have for $x\geq M$ and $0<|\epsilon|<\delta$, then $|x^{1-\epsilon}-L|<1$. Pick an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon<\delta$ and that $1-\epsilon>0$, then $x^{1-\epsilon}<L+1$ for all such $x\geq M$. Taking $x\rightarrow\infty$ will make the latter inequality blowing up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
So, when in the last inequality we take $x \to \infty$, this will cause that $x^{1-\epsilon} \to \infty$ thus, since this is strictly smaller that $L + 1$ , one can assume that $ L =\infty$?

Comment: It is true that the limit is $\infty$, but it needs some justification.